# How does the bre.ad (http://bre.ad) background work?

Tags: jquery, css, html

[Bre.ad](http://bre.ad) has this background where it keeps moving and there is an illusion of a baker's truck moving on the road. I was wondering how that was done and can it be done so that the image is moving vertically instead of horizontally?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The entire background is this long png file, and the city scapes and clouds are transparent background pngs that are layered over it in multiple divs.

Background (Town):

[image: Background]

CityScape:

[image: Cityscape]

The relevant HTML from the page source:

```
<div id="bread-world">
    <div id="puffyclouds" style="background-position: 0 -75px"></div>
    <div id="cityscape" style="background-position: 0 105px;"></div>
    <div id="ocean"></div>
    <div id="town" style="background-position: 0 0;"></div>
    <div id="truck"></div>
</div>
```

and the relevant CSS from [`all.css`](http://bread-css.s3.amazonaws.com/gzip/all.css)

```
#town{
    background:url('//bread-images.s3.amazonaws.com/invite/town.png?1308363721') 
    repeat-x 542px 0px;
    width:5806px;
    left:0;
    bottom:0;
    height:599px;
    position:absolute
    }
```

and similarly for the other divs. The `repeat-x` property is used to repeat the background so as to mimic the effect of continuous scrolling. Also, the left end of the image and the right end line up, so as to give a smooth transition.

The animation is done by [`homepage.js`](http://bread-js.s3.amazonaws.com/gzip/pages/homepage.js) which slowly shifts the `background-position` linearly. The relevant lines are:

```
function r(){
    m.css({backgroundPosition:"0 -75px"}).animate({backgroundPosition:q+"px -75px"},{duration:n,easing:"linear"}),
    k.css({backgroundPosition:"0 0"}).animate({backgroundPosition:o+"px 0"},{duration:n,easing:"linear"}),
    l.css({backgroundPosition:"0 105px"}).animate({backgroundPosition:p+"px 105px"},{duration:n,easing:"linear",complete:r})
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Multiple divs are used, with each div having its own background. Stacking them up forms the illusion of a layered background. That way, each layer can move separate from the others giving the illusion that some are farther away than others. JavaScript is used to slowly shift the `background-position` property of each div element. The speed at which this is done is different for each layer.

Comment: Oh and there is a background:repeat property to make the image loop? Is there a library that achieves this effect?

Comment: Yes, `repeat-x` is used. jQuery is very good for animation, although something like this would be pretty trivial to do in pure JavaScript with `setInterval` or `setTimeout`

Comment: This is known as a parallax effect, BTW.

Comment: @Shauna Are you sure. Isnt the parallax effect where you stack up different layers and make them move to create a relative displacement effect?

Comment: From wikipedia: "Parallax is an apparent displacement or difference in the apparent position of an object viewed along two different lines of sight, and is measured by the angle or semi-angle of inclination between those two lines." In a nutshell, the "closer" ones move faster than the ones in the back. bre.ad does this, just automatically and make it look like the "camera" is following/focused on the car. It's still the same principle.

Answer (score 0):

This has been created by animating the `background-position` of a large image. You can switch to vertical movement by animating the vertical position of the `background-image`. This way you only show part of the image at once.

You can use jQuery or a similar javascript library to animate this property.